# Cannot Drag and Drop Email's between Folders

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, windows-10, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

Since upgrading to outlook 365 (2016) and importing my old email, whenever I attempt to drag an email to a different folder I get the following error message:

"Cannot find this file verify the path and filename are correct"

I'm using the Outlook desktop app on windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update to Microsoft Office fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to fix this depending on the answer to this question: Are you able to view the emails in the folders that you are dragging them to?

If you can see the emails in those folders, I'd recommend that you close out of Outlook, and run SCANPST/SCANOST on your mail folders. Those utilities would be in your Office directory under Program Files.

If you cannot see the emails in those folders, open the Account Settings box from the File menu, go to the Data Files tab, and verify that the data files referenced are where they are supposed to be. If they are, close out of Outlook, and run ScanPST/ScanOST on them.

Comment: I can see email in each of the folders.  As soon as I try to drag the email the error pops up.  SCANPST did not help fix the problem.  I can create a completely new profile and datafile and the problem persists.

Comment: I have also tried reinstalling outlook.

Comment: So I just reinstalled outlook, create a pop3 profile.  Created a draft email and tried to move it and the error pops up.  As this is a new profile and datafile, surely there must be some bogus registry entries or something causing problems that aren't being cleared/reset with a reinstall.  I have also tried changing the location of the pst file and giving full read/write permission of the folder to the "Everyone" policy.

Comment: You could try doing a manual uninstall as detailed in this KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739501

Comment: Thanks,  actually I have tried that too,  it really is a weird problem.  Its like some sort of profile setting is remaining.

Comment: Well, to rule that out, can you create a new user on your system and add an account there?

Comment: Good tip - so I just did that but the problem exists on the new account as well.  I'm getting close to throwing PC's at walls. :)

Comment: That is bizarre. I'm not sure what else to suggest at that point. It seems to be systemic so besides a reinstall of Windows, I've got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Although without any error notification, I was also unable to drag and drop emails between folders with Windows 10 and Microsoft Outlook 2016. I tried restarting the program or [hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>](http://saniac.com/drag-and-drop-stops-working-in-outlook/), with no avail. The solution in my case was closing some other program (IZArc) open in another window, which in fact was waiting for my click to continue execution.